# Move div when scroll position is lower than its top property

Tags: jquery, scroll, menu

https://jsfiddle.net/9o73880z/ - fiddle will probably help to understand what I will wrote here :)

I'm making fixed(but position:absolute, because in the end it is really long and I need it to scroll :)) menu on my page.

It expands on click (the V near NAV). It goes with the user when he scrolls the page.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var sctre = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(sctre >= 95) {
        if($(".trefl-nav-switch").hasClass("trefl-zwiniete")) {$(".trefl-head-top").css({"padding-top":"40px","top":sctre-41,"background":"#fff"});}
        if($(".trefl-nav-switch").hasClass("trefl-rozwiniete") && sctre < menu_top_pos) {$(".trefl-head-top").css({"padding-top":"40x","top":sctre-41,"background":"#fff"});}
    }
    if(sctre < 95) {
        $(".trefl-head-top").css({"padding-top":"0px","top":"75px"});
    }
});
```

When scroll position is over 95 it stars to go with the user (value for just the page compability I'm working on), BUT only when the nav button is folded 
(hasClass('zwiniete')). When it is unfolded (hasclass(rozwiniete)) it stops, so user can scroll the menu, not the page itself).

And now is my question, which I don't really know how to achieve:

1. Can I somehow force browser to scroll only what's inside "trefl-head-top" when it is unfolded

   2. If I can't after looking at my code, I've tried to do something like - Record position(top property) of trefl-head-top when I click to unfold it (var menu_top_pos), and IF menu is unfolded AND scroll position is < smaller than menu_top_pos, change the "top" css. But unfortunately I can't see the effect :(

`if($(".trefl-nav-switch").hasClass("trefl-rozwiniete") && sctre < menu_top_pos) {$(".trefl-head-top").css({"padding-top":"40x","top":sctre-41,"background":"#fff"});}`

That's the code responsible.

I will appreciate any help, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open the menu, change it's css position to fixed and add overflow-y scroll with max-height of the menu, it will trigger the scrolling of the menu once it reach specified height:

```
if ($(".trefl-nav-switch").hasClass("trefl-zwiniete")) {
  ...

  $(".trefl-head-top").css("position",'fixed');
  $(".trefl-head-top").css("overflow-y",'scroll');
  $(".trefl-head-top").css("max-height",'100px');
  $(".trefl-head-top").css("top",'0px');
  ...
}
```

You will need to set `$(".trefl-head-top").css("position",'absolute');`  when it's closed along with resetting the rest of the properties. You might need to fiddle with the top property to position it correctly but you are already doing similar in your code

Comment: max-height can be a problem, since on smaller resolutions some position would transfer from one to two lines.

Comment: it's up to you how you decide when to  trigger the overflow scroll -  you can calculate it dynamicaly based on the viewport , or sum up the height of the menu elements you want to be visible for example

Comment: thank you @mike_t for help. It was pretty obvious from the begining, I think I saw somwhere that my div has to have "position:absolute" in order to scroll that div. Now I can have fullscreen nav and scroll only it.